# dropping NA values in rows if all columns contain NA's but keep the rows which contain at least one result

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data and I am trying to remove the NA values from it.

I apply the following:

```
data %>% 
  head(20) %>% 
  drop_na(contains("gvkey"))
```

Which removes all the rows. I want to keep rows 12 and 16 since these two rows have values in one of the `gvkey[X]` columns. If there was a vale in `gvkey2` I would want to keep these rows also. The same applys for `gvkey[1]...[5]`.

Data:

```
data <- structure(list(cod = structure(c(12L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("01 Unassigned", 
"02 US corporation", "03 Foreign corp, incl. state-owned", "04 US individual", 
"05 Foreign individual", "06 US government", "07 Foreign government", 
"08 US local government", "09 US state government", "US university", 
"Foreign university", "US institute", "Foreign institute", "US hospital/med inst", 
"Foreign hospital/med inst"), class = "factor"), cod_fix = c(32L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), pdpass = c(12832332L, 11624193L, 12549858L, 11170486L, 
10513915L, 13143949L, 10817896L, 12517845L, 13028479L, 12986393L, 
11719402L, 12298245L, 12249804L, 12898008L, 13100249L, 12298245L, 
10256638L, -19842L, -19842L, 11485267L), standard_name = c("& AEROSPACE FOUND", 
"& COMMUNICATIONS", "& DESIGN LTD", "& FR", "& SA FAB DEBAUCHES", 
"& SON INC", "& YET INC", "&&T TECH CO LTD", "01 COMMUNIQUE LAB INC", 
"01 DB METRAVIB", "02 MICRO INC", "02 MICRO INT LTD", "02 TECH INC", 
"02IC INC", "02MICRO", "02MICRO INT LTD", "03 CO", "080 STUDIO INC", 
"0KAMOTO ; SHOSUKE", "1"), uspto_assignee = c(835951L, 721167L, 
806186L, 182855L, 182585L, NA, 30140L, 802588L, NA, NA, 729315L, 
782400L, 775728L, 825676L, NA, 782400L, 641605L, NA, NA, 708378L
), pdpco1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 138961L, 
NA, NA, NA, 138961L, NA, NA, NA, NA), source = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "m2006", NA, NA, NA, "m2006", 
NA, NA, NA, NA), begyr1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 2000L, NA, NA, NA, 2000L, NA, NA, NA, NA), gvkey1 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 138961L, NA, NA, NA, 
138961L, NA, NA, NA, NA), endyr1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2006L, NA, NA, NA, 2006L, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    pdpco2 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_), begyr2 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_), gvkey2 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), endyr2 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), pdpco3 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), begyr3 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), gvkey3 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), endyr3 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), pdpco4 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), begyr4 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), gvkey4 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), endyr4 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), pdpco5 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), begyr5 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), gvkey5 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), endyr5 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  filter_at(vars(starts_with('gvkey')), any_vars(!is.na(.)))
```

Output:

```
                                 cod cod_fix   pdpass    standard_name uspto_assignee pdpco1 source begyr1 gvkey1
1 03 Foreign corp, incl. state-owned       0 12298245 02 MICRO INT LTD         782400 138961  m2006   2000 138961
2 03 Foreign corp, incl. state-owned       0 12298245  02MICRO INT LTD         782400 138961  m2006   2000 138961
  endyr1 pdpco2 begyr2 gvkey2 endyr2 pdpco3 begyr3 gvkey3 endyr3 pdpco4 begyr4 gvkey4 endyr4 pdpco5 begyr5 gvkey5
1   2006     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
2   2006     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
  endyr5
1     NA
2     NA
```

Answer (score 1):

With `base R`, we can use `Reduce` with `lapply`

```
data[!Reduce(`&`, lapply(data[startsWith(names(data), 'gvkey')], is.na)),]
#                                  cod cod_fix   pdpass    standard_name uspto_assignee pdpco1 source
#12 03 Foreign corp, incl. state-owned       0 12298245 02 MICRO INT LTD         782400 138961  m2006
#16 03 Foreign corp, incl. state-owned       0 12298245  02MICRO INT LTD         782400 138961  m2006
#   begyr1 gvkey1 endyr1 pdpco2 begyr2 gvkey2 endyr2 pdpco3 begyr3 gvkey3 endyr3 pdpco4 begyr4 gvkey4
#12   2000 138961   2006     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
#16   2000 138961   2006     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
#   endyr4 pdpco5 begyr5 gvkey5 endyr5
#12     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
#16     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
```